# Spark Scala - Datetime to Unix_time

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working on a windowing function to look at 24 hour time periods and calculating a min/max of a column in that time period and finding the largest difference for any 24 hour period. My timestamp is in the form of: `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a`. When trying to convert this to unix time, only a handful of values are being converted properly. You can notice in the Current Output, some 24 hour start/end times are incorrect:

I.e 01/01/2000 1:53PM as the start is saying 24 hours from then is 01/02/2000 01:53:AM. When checking the unixtime `946691580` to a date converter it comes up as `01/01/2000 1:53AM` and not PM. So my issue lies somewhere in converting my `Date` field to unix_time.

Once my data is formatted, I plan to create a view on top of the data frame and using spark sql to calculate the maximum difference between the two columns.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Sample Input (Where I think my unix time is incorrect):

```
+------------+------------------+---------+-------+-------+
|TemperatureF|              Date|timestamp|MinTemp|MaxTemp|
+------------+------------------+---------+-------+-------+
|        35.1|01/01/2000 1:53 AM|946691580|   28.0|   36.0|
|        34.0|01/01/2000 1:53 PM|946691580|   28.0|   36.0|
|        35.1|01/01/2000 2:53 AM|946695180|   28.0|   36.0|
|        33.1|01/01/2000 2:53 PM|946695180|   28.0|   36.0|
|        34.0|01/01/2000 3:53 AM|946698780|   28.0|   36.0|
|        32.0|01/01/2000 3:53 PM|946698780|   28.0|   36.0|
|        32.0|01/01/2000 4:53 AM|946702380|   28.0|   37.4|
|        32.0|01/01/2000 4:53 PM|946702380|   28.0|   37.4|
|        30.9|01/01/2000 5:53 AM|946705980|   28.0|   37.4|
+------------+------------------+---------+-------+-------+
```

Current Output

```
+-------------------+---------+-------------------+-------+-------+
|              Start|timestamp|                end|MinTemp|MaxTemp|
+-------------------+---------+-------------------+-------+-------+
| 01/01/2000 1:53 AM|946691580|01/02/2000 01:53 AM|   28.0|   36.0|
| 01/01/2000 1:53 PM|946691580|01/02/2000 01:53 AM|   28.0|   36.0|
| 01/01/2000 2:53 AM|946695180|01/02/2000 02:53 AM|   28.0|   36.0|
| 01/01/2000 2:53 PM|946695180|01/02/2000 02:53 AM|   28.0|   36.0|
| 01/01/2000 3:53 AM|946698780|01/02/2000 03:53 AM|   28.0|   36.0|
| 01/01/2000 3:53 PM|946698780|01/02/2000 03:53 AM|   28.0|   36.0|
| 01/01/2000 4:53 AM|946702380|01/02/2000 04:53 AM|   28.0|   37.4|
| 01/01/2000 4:53 PM|946702380|01/02/2000 04:53 AM|   28.0|   37.4|
| 01/01/2000 5:53 AM|946705980|01/02/2000 05:53 AM|   28.0|   37.4|
| 01/01/2000 5:53 PM|946705980|01/02/2000 05:53 AM|   28.0|   37.4|
| 01/01/2000 6:37 PM|946708620|01/02/2000 06:37 AM|   28.0|   37.4|
| 01/01/2000 6:53 AM|946709580|01/02/2000 06:53 AM|   28.0|   37.4|
+-------------------+---------+-------------------+-------+-------+
```

Current Code:

```
val data = osh.select(col("TemperatureF"), concat(format_string("%02d",col("Month")),lit("/"),format_string("%02d",col("Day")),lit("/"),col("Year"),lit(" "),col("TimeCST")).as("Date")).filter(col("TemperatureF") > -9999)

val oshdata = data.withColumn("timestamp",unix_timestamp(to_timestamp(col("Date"),"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")))

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
val myWindow = Window.orderBy("timestamp").rangeBetween(Window.currentRow, 86400)
val myData = oshdata.withColumn("MinTemp", min(col("TemperatureF")).over(myWindow))
  .withColumn("MaxTemp",max(col("TemperatureF")).over(myWindow))

  myData.show()

myData.createOrReplaceTempView("oshView")


spark.sqlContext.sql("Select Date as Start,timestamp, from_unixtime(timestamp+86400,'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a') as end,MinTemp,MaxTemp from oshView").show(25)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are parsing the `Date` column using `"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"`, so it ignores the am/pm marker. Instead, you should be using `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a`. Note it is `hh` for 12-hour time values and not `HH`.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Need to update `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a` to be a `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a`.

Output now:

```
+-------------------+---------+-------------------+-------+-------+
|              Start|timestamp|                end|MinTemp|MaxTemp|
+-------------------+---------+-------------------+-------+-------+
|01/01/2000 12:53 AM|946687980|01/02/2000 12:53 AM|   28.0|   36.0|
| 01/01/2000 1:53 AM|946691580|01/02/2000 01:53 AM|   28.0|   36.0|
| 01/01/2000 2:53 AM|946695180|01/02/2000 02:53 AM|   28.0|   36.0|
| 01/01/2000 3:53 AM|946698780|01/02/2000 03:53 AM|   28.0|   36.0|
| 01/01/2000 4:53 AM|946702380|01/02/2000 04:53 AM|   28.0|   37.4|
| 01/01/2000 5:53 AM|946705980|01/02/2000 05:53 AM|   28.0|   37.4|
| 01/01/2000 6:53 AM|946709580|01/02/2000 06:53 AM|   28.0|   37.4|
| 01/01/2000 7:53 AM|946713180|01/02/2000 07:53 AM|   28.0|   37.4|
| 01/01/2000 8:53 AM|946716780|01/02/2000 08:53 AM|   28.0|   37.4|
+-------------------+---------+-------------------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably boils down to your time parsing being incorrect:

```
unix_timestamp(to_timestamp($"Date", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"))
```